# Share an instance of a QMainWindow through shared memory

Tags: c++, qt, shared-memory

Is it possible to share an instance of an `QMainWindow` (or a `QWidget`) through `QSharedMemory`?

I have been looking for some examples, and as far as I understood the problem seems to be that the `QDataStream&operator>>` doesn't know how to deserialise a `QObject`...right?

here my attempt: I serialise and copy the instance of my `MainWindow` into the shared memory

```cpp
void MainWindow::loadIntoMemory()
{
    ...
    QBuffer buffer;
    buffer.open(QBuffer::WriteOnly);
    QDataStream out(&buffer);
    ... // omitting - if this == nullptr -
    out << this; // <-- serialising the MainWindow
    int size = buffer.size();
    sharedMemory.create(size)); // omitting if statement to avoid post verbosity
    sharedMemory.lock();
    char *to = (char*)sharedMemory.data();
    const char *from = buffer.data().data();
    memcpy(to, from, qMin(sharedMemory.size(), size));
    ...
}
```

but it comes to deserialise it from another app:

```cpp
QMainWindow parentApp;
QBuffer buffer;
QDataStream in(&buffer); 
in >> parentApp;
```

I got the error: `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('QDataStream' and 'QMainWindow') qchar.h:663:28: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'QMainWindow' to 'QChar &' for 2nd argument`.

I have been also considering that maybe sharing the memory address of `this` could be an option. Something like:

- saving `this` (a `QMainWindow*) as a` QbitArray`
- serialise it
- copying into the shared memory and load it from another application

but I wouldn't know how to do it...

**EDIT**
The ultimate goal of this Application would be the following:
The Application "A" (the one reading from the shared memory) is a child process (`QProcess`) of Application "B" (the one writing into the shared memoery). Application "A" is able to dynamically instantiate `QDockWidget`s which should dock onto the `MainWindow` of Application "B".

Since I cannot access any parent element from a child process, I was considering to share the Application "B"'s `MainWindow` from a shared memory and instantiate:

```
QDockWidget dock = new QDockWidget(parentAppMainWindow) // pointer red from the QSharedMemory
```

**EDIT (second step):**

As suggested by @G.M. one possible approach is to exchange the window id by (in this case) a shared memory. So I refactored the above presented `loadIntoMemory`function so that "Application B" (the parent) shared its `MainWindow`'`id` into the shared memory :

```cpp
void MainWindow::loadIntoMemory() // from application B
{
    // I instantiate "out" as QDataStream using the QBuffer buffer (Write only)
    ...
    WId id = this->winId();
    out << id; // <-- serialize id into the QDataStream
    qDebug() << id // print the id
    ...
    // calculate the size of the buffer and memcpy buffer into the 
}
```

then I read the value from `sharedMemory` from `Application A` (the `child` `Qprocess` of `Application B` as follows:

```cpp
WId parentWinId;
QBuffer buffer;
QDataStream in(&buffer);  // read the id
sharedMemory.lock();
buffer.setData((char*)sharedMemory.constData(), sharedMemory.size());
buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadOnly);
in >> parentWinId;
sharedMemory.unlock();
qDebug() <<"The parent window Id is" << parentWinId; // parentWinId has exactly the same id as in the previous code block
qDebug() << "Here a representation of the parent window " << QWindow::fromWinId(parentWinId); // CRASH
```

but "Application A" crashes.

Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: This looks like an xy-problem.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: ***Is it possible to share an instance of an QMainWindow (or a QWidget) through QSharedMemory?*** I would expect that to be difficult to impossible to do correctly because there is thread specific and process specific initialization tied to the widget. You are not even supposed to directly access a widget in a different thread.

Comment: I edited the post...I hope it make more sense now. thank you for your comments

Comment: Having multiple processes work on one GUI is possible - within reason - at least in windows, but I can't imagine there to be a cross platform solution. Even if it were possible it's a pretty bad idea thanks to all the complexities that introduces. Better to go with a classic plugin approach

Comment: @Voo I see... I am just reading about qtplugins (on the official documentation). Could you maybe point me to the right direction? do you think I can keep the parent child application structure? Thank you very very much

Comment: You don't need to exchange the `QMainWindow` in the manner proposed.  Just exchange the window id by some means and then use [`QWidget::createWindowContainer(id)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer) to create a wrapper widget.

Comment: @G.M. I love your idea, it sounds like a very elegant solution, but somehow it doesn't work here...I get the parent's `QMainWindow` id from the shared memory, but the child process crashes when I try `QMainWindow::createWindowContainer(QWindow::fromWinId(id));`. It even crashes if I try: `QWidget::find(id)`. Any idea why?

Comment: @ddgg If it really `"...doesn't work here"` then, again, you'll need to provide a [mcve].  Otherwise all we can do is guess.

Comment: I edited the post again...please tell me if I should write the whole functions - I simply didn't want to bore you. thank you!

Comment: @G.M. I isolated this problem in other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70801544/get-pointer-to-qmainwindow-from-child-qprocess...would you like to take a look at it?

Comment: Well, I convinced myself that there are no solutions with this approach. @Voo what do you mean with a `classic plugin approach`? Would you like to share an example or a workflow? thank you very much. And thank you all for helping