# get pointer to QMainWindow from child QProcess

Tags: c++, qt5

I have an `parent` "Application A" which starts a `QProcess` "Application B".

From "Application B" I would like to have a local representation of "Application A"'s `MainWindow`. From a comment in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70775929/share-an-instance-of-a-qmainwindow-through-shared-memory?noredirect=1#comment125137299_70775929) I learned that I could achieve this by: *exchanging the window id by some means and then use QWidget::createWindowContainer(id) to create a wrapper widget*

```
QWindow *QWindow::fromWinId(WId id)
```

So I'm sharing "Application A"'s `MainWindow` id via shared memory:

```cpp
void MainWindow::manageSharedMemory()
{
    ...
    WId thisAppWinId = this->winId();
    ...
    // load thisAppWinId into the shared memory
}
```

In "Application B" I then access `thisAppWinId` as follow:

```cpp
void MainWindow::get_parent_window()
{
    QBuffer buffer;
    QDataStream in(&buffer);
    WId parentAppWinId;
    sharedMemory.lock();
    buffer.setData((char*)sharedMemory.constData(), sharedMemory.size());
    buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadOnly);
    in >> parentAppWinId;
    qDebug() <<"Parent WId " << parentAppWinId; // here I can read the same WId as defined in Application A
    sharedMemory.unlock();
    sharedMemory.detach();
    QObject* parent = QWindow::fromWinId(parentAppWinId);
}
```

but the application crashes.

I tried to pass "Application B"'s `MainWindow` as an argument of `QWindow::fromWinId(this->winId());` for debugging purposes: the application doesn't crash, but "Application B"'s `MainWindow` size changes...

Why is this happening? Is this the cause of the crash in the first case?

How can I avoid crashing when using `QWindow::fromWinId(parentAppWinId);`?

p.s. the ultimate goal would be to be able to instantiate `QObject`s (such as `QDockWidget`) from *Application B* as children of *Application A*'s `MainWindow`

**UPDATE!!**

it is working on Linux! The application doesn't crash but I cannot dock a QDockWidget into *Application A*'s `MainWindow` when I use

```cpp
QWidget* parentRepresentation = QWidget::createWindowContainer(QWindow::fromWinId(parentAppWinId));
```

nor I can

```cpp
QWidget* parentRepresentation = QWidget::find(parentAppWinId)
```

because it returns a `nullptr`

I have updated the minimale reproducible example.

Thank you very very much

---

**FOR MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE**

this example does not use a shared memory, but shares the window Id as an argument of the QProcess. The crash occurs in the same context.

*APPLICATION A*

```
//mainwindow.h
#include <QtWidgets>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void startAppB();
private:
    QProcess* m_child;

};
```

```cpp
// mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    m_child = new QProcess(this);
    setWindowTitle("Application A");
    startAppB();
}

void MainWindow::startAppB()
{
    QString rel_path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/../../../../child/child.app/Contents/MacOS/";
    QString app = rel_path + "child";
    QStringList args;
    WId myId = this->winId();
    qDebug() << myId;
    args << QString::number(myId);
    m_child->start(app, args, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
}
```

*APPLICATION B*

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
//    argv[1] is the WId id of the MainWindow's parent process
    WId parentId = std::strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    MainWindow w(nullptr, parentId);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

```
// mainwindow.h
#include <QtWidgets>
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr, WId parentId = 0);
    WId parentId;
};
```

```cpp
// mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent, WId parentId)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setWindowTitle("Application B");
    this->parentId = parentId;
    qInfo() << "The parentId is: "<< parentId;

    WId parentAppWinId = this->parentId;
    QWidget* parentRepresentation = QWidget::createWindowContainer(QWindow::fromWinId(parentAppWinId));
    qDebug() << parentRepresentation; // QWindowContainer(0xhex)

    QDockWidget* dock = new QDockWidget(parentRepresentation);
    dock->setFloating(true);
    dock->show(); // it appears but I can't even drag it
}
```

Comment: Try to pass parent id as a command-line argument when creating a child process and see if the crash reccurs. This will hell to determine if shared memory code is responcible or not

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik thank you for your suggestion and I am sorry for the late reply I could give it a try only now. Unfortuntely it doesn't work. The application keeps crashing. Are you sure that it is not related to the fact that when I pass `this->winId()` "Application B"'s `MainWindow` changes its size? it looks to me that it get destroyed and then constructed again...

Comment: I don't know. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik sure! here it is!

Comment: You cannot achieve your ultimate goal, see documentation: *dow should not be used to manipulate the underlying native window (besides re-parenting), or to observe state changes of the native window*.

Comment: well...fair enough. May I give it another try? Would writing a plugin help in such a case? and if yes, would someone be willing to share a workflow example? Thank you all very much anyway!